# SQL Merge Two SELECT statements together

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL query which returns 2 results which are the same only different by a where clause.

I would like to have them combined and group them under the user names. At the moment the two results are displayed but the results are not fully combined and the users are shown twice because of the two select statements.

How can I combine the two to create a single result.

The SQL query is as follows

```
SELECT 
COUNT (asings.user_id), 
    post_status.status_id as status_id, 
    users.name, 
    users.id as user_id 
    from asigns 
LEFT JOIN 
    post_status on asigns.post_id = post_status.post_id 
RIGHT JOIN 
    users on asigns.user_id = users.id 
WHERE 
    post_status.status_id = 2 
GROUP BY users.id

UNION

SELECT 
COUNT(asigns.user_id), 
    post_status.status_id as status_id, 
    users.name, 
    users.id from asigns 
LEFT JOIN 
    post_status on asigns.post_id = post_status.post_id 
RIGHT JOIN 
    users on asigns.user_id = users.id 
WHERE 
    post_status.status_id = 3 
GROUP BY users.id
```

[image]

See in this photo the usernames are appearing twice, what I want is to join the two username, and move count as two different columns depending on the status_id

How can I solve this. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a single query with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(ps.status_id = 2) AS cnt_2,
    SUM(ps.status_id = 3) AS cnt_3,
    u.name, 
    u.id as user_id 
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN assigns a ON a.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN post_status ps ON a.post_id = ps.post_id   
GROUP BY u.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SELECT distinct for the union:

```sql
SELECT distinct * FROM ([FIRST SELECT] UNION [SECOND SELECT])
```

Or GROUP BY username

```sql
SELECT * FROM ([FIRST SELECT] UNION [SECOND SELECT]) GROUP BY username
```

**BUT I suggest to review your both selects, if it differs just in the where clause so use where clause with the operator `OR` and you handle it just by one SELECT**

Answer (score 0):

Although your are using a `LEFT` and a `RIGHT` join and implicitly an `INNER` join between `users` and `asigns`, the `WHERE` clause transforms all the joins to `INNER` joins, because you are picking only the matching rows from `post_status`.

So, you only need `INNER` joins and conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(ps.status_id = 2), 0) counter_2, 
       COALESCE(SUM(ps.status_id = 3), 0) counter_3,  
       u.name, 
       u.id AS user_id 
FROM users u
INNER JOIN asigns a ON a.user_id = u.id  
INNER JOIN post_status ps ON ps.post_id  = a.post_id 
WHERE ps.status_id IN (2, 3) 
GROUP BY u.id;
```